# Why the treeset can't find this element?

Tags: java, collections

I have a Treeset where People are sorted with their money, but equality is made on name.
I have jack and jackie with the same name "jackie" and they are thought equals. `jack` added to the Treeset, `jackie` is not.
The javadoc on `contains()` says :

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e
>   such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Unfortunately the line

```
System.out.println(peoples.contains(jackie));
```

returns false when `jackie.equals(jack)` returns true. Why ?

Here is the full code.

```
public class UsingSet {


 public static void main(String[] args) {


         People jo = new People("Jo");      
         People jack = new People("Jackie");
         jack.setMoney(12);
         People jim = new People("Jimmy");
         jim.setMoney(150);
         People john = new People("John");

         TreeSet<People> peoples = new TreeSet<People>();
         peoples.add(jo);
         peoples.add(jack);
         peoples.add(jim);
         peoples.add(john);


        People jackie = new People("Jackie");
        System.out.println("equality ? "+(jackie.equals(jack)));
        System.out.println(peoples.contains(jackie));

    }
}

class People extends Object implements Comparable<People> {

    public static long maxCount() {
        return 25000000000L;
    }

    String name;
    Float  money = 1000f;

    public People(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.length());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        People other = (People) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(People other) {

        int result = this.money.compareTo(other.getMoney());
        if (result == 0){
            //finding a second criteria
            return this.name.compareTo(other.getName());        
        }else{
            return result;
        }
    }


    public float getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public void setMoney(float money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT** :
The javadoc says that the Treeset based on the *Natural order* must have a `equals()` coherent with `compareTo()`. The Treeset with a `Comparator` must not.

So I modified slightly the code like that :

```
Comparator<People> compareByMoney = new Comparator<People>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(People p1, People p2) {
    int result = p1.money.compareTo(p2.getMoney());
    if (result == 0){
    //finding a second criteria
    return p1.name.compareTo(p2.getName());     
    }else{
      return result;
    }           
}

};      

TreeSet<People> peoples = new TreeSet<People>(compareByMoney);
    ...
    System.out.println(peoples.contains(jackie)); //--> true
```

Comment: FYI, it prints true for me. http://ideone.com/anwxoX

Comment: I corrected the last line of the main : I test System.out.println(peoples.contains(jackie)); and it's false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jackie is not formally `equals` to jack since they don't have the same amount of money (note that your equals method only check the name, not the money).

You're using the money attribute to compare them in your treeset. Since jackie has 1000 for money and jack has 12, they're not the same for the treeset and hence contains return false..

If you do

```
People jackie = new People("Jackie");
jackie.setMoney(12);
```

you'll the that it outputs true for both, or aternatively if your `compareTo` method was just :

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(People other) {
       return this.name.compareTo(other.getName());     
    }
```

It will also output `true`.

So you need to change your `equals` method to compare the amount of `money`, or just use the name in your `compareTo` method.

If you read the doc :

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.)
>   This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals
>   operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons
>   using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are
>   deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal

Consistent :

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
>   equals **if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value
>   as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C**

With your code we have :

```
System.out.println("equality ? "+(jackie.equals(jack))); //equality ? true
System.out.println(jackie.compareTo(jack)); //1
```

The natural ordering of your class is not consistent with equals. So don't expect your treeSet to have the normal behaviour.

Comment: Yes, my CompareTo is not related to equals() and I don't want to change this. But the javadoc says explicitely that contains is based on equals(). I could also have use a Comparator for the Treeset and remove the Comparable interface for people.

Comment: @NicolasZozol Your equals method is not consistent with your natural comparator. Check my edit.

Comment: Great answer :) **must be consistent with equals** is the problem. So means that if  `compareTo() == 0`, then `equals()` should return true.  But it means that Treeset are quite limitated.

Comment: @NicolasZozol What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I'm running a Java training, so it's mainly theory. I've added an Edit to find a good solution : The people are still equals with name, but the Treeset compare people with their money using the Comparator.

Comment: @NicolasZozol Yes you can provide a custom comparator. Note that if you add two different people (by their name) with the same amount of money, the set will only keep one of them with the comparator you provided.

Comment: Totally true, that's why I just added a second criteria for my Comparator - maybe not the best design.

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code,and it println "true"

Comment: It is not answer. add it to in comment section.

Comment: I don't have the permission to add comment .

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the binary tree fist to know about the reason

[image]

compareTo() method use to insert any element in the tree (not the equals() method). 
jack and jackie having the different amount of money. so as per compartTo() method both are not the same object. and since compareTo() method is returning false. that is why contains() method is also returning false

```
    People jackie = new People("Jackie");
    System.out.println("equality ? "+(jackie.equals(jack)));
    System.out.println("compareTo ? "+(jackie.compareTo(jack)));
    System.out.println(peoples.contains(jackie));
```

if your equals() method is returning the true then your compareTo() method should also show the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't notice your algorithm is not correct for your purpose.

Ok, you add `jack` and `jackie` to a TreeSet.
Jack got the `name ="jackie"` and the `money="12"`
Jackie got the `name="jackie"` and the `money= <defaultValue> ="1000"`

When you override the method `equals` in People class (mainly, it check the name of 2 object), you got by this way your check `"equality ? "+(jackie.equals(jack))`, it's obviously true

But, when you override the method `compareTo` in People class, you check first the money between your 2 objects, so previously you declare `jack` and `jackie` without the same money attribute value. Indeed, they are different, because your money check != 0 and your second check on the name is ignored.

Well, if you change:
`People jackie = new People("Jackie");`
in 
`People jackie = new People("Jackie");
jackie.setMoney(12);`

You launch it, magic!
Console output:
`equality ? true`
`true`

Problem solved dude